# pip3 install matplotlib fails with Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am new to Python, but not programming or Mac OS X. I have searched the internet for hours and I've tried every solution I can find, including manually installing/uninstalling just about everything. The exact same command works perfectly using pip, just not pip3.

I can't even remember half the solutions I've tried, but here's what I can remember:
-installed numpy manually
-installed anaconda
-reinstall python/python3
-installed pkg-config manually
-installed numpy manually

Any and all help greatly appreciated!

Full Terminal Output:

```
rover-230-17:~ unwrittenrainbow$ pip3 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
Using cached matplotlib-1.5.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.1]
                python: yes [3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015,
                        20:58:59)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]]
              platform: yes [darwin]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
                        it after matplotlib.]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.6.0]
                   png: yes [version 1.6.20]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for numpy>=1.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/2h/k8n0gw311f58vnd7jm3b8tmh0000gn/T/pip-build-xduaxugd/matplotlib/setup.py", line 277, in <module>
    **extra_args
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.6')
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing, version not identified]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]


----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in           /private/var/folders/2h/k8n0gw311f58vnd7jm3b8tmh0000gn/T/pip-build-xduaxugd/matplotlib
```

Comment: You have an issue with your certs `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`, so pip is not installing dependent packages from https://pypi.python.org/ - fix your certs or manually install all the dependent packages.

Comment: How does one fix said certs? You mean the security cert from pypi?

Comment: Fixed. I just wiped the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the depedencies yourself:

```
         gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
            gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
             tkagg: yes [installing, version not identified]
             wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
               gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
               agg: yes [installing]
             cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
         windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
```

You can use `pip` to install these,
`pip install pycairo pygtk wxPython`

Comment: May need to fix cert issue first.